# Catch fatal error on gearman php workers

Tags: php, worker, gearman

When worker job failed by fatal error, I cant catch this error, so I cant send result to gearman server, and server does not remove job from queue and it try to doing this job again, supervisor restart worker and worker fail agian. So i can receive infinite loop until restart server :

gearman send job to worker -> worker failed by fatal error -> job not remove from queue -> supervisor restart worker -> gearman send job to worker -> ...

(of course, only if I can not quickly fix error in php). How can i remove this job from queue (or fix this problem another way)?

Simple example:

```
$worker->addFunction('test', 'test');
while($worker->work());

function test()
{
  $a = [];
  //fatal error
  $a->fatal();
}
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: `whiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiile`

Answer (score 0):

If you enter like me searching for a method to catch a fatal error and send it back to the worker.
So, you need to use the function set_exception_handle and set_error_handle
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Then, you should implement in your client a failCallback and a exceptionCallback to capture those fails.
On the Worker, you must add a function that send back the exception.

```
public function exception_handler($exception) {

    $this->job->sendException('Boom');

}
```

The client will catch the exception on the callback

```
public function verifyExceptionTask (GearmanTask $task) {
    $m = $task->data();
    echo "ID Unique: " . $task->unique() . "\n";
    echo "Exception: {$m} " . GEARMAN_WORK_EXCEPTION . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This line is creating an infinite loop:

```
while($worker->work());
```

Comment: you make a mistake, another type of infinite loop:)